# Is there a way to move n tabs forward?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I'm familiar with `ngT`, which will move n tabs backward. Is there an equivalent way to move forward? I know that if I have 5 tabs open and I'm on tab 3, I can use `3gT` to move backwards to tab 5. However, this quickly becomes unwieldy as the number of tabs increases and I lose track of the exact number I'm on at a given time.

Comment: I am a bit worried that you using 1 tab == 1 file workflow. This will become cumbersome. You may want to look into Vim's buffers. Some links on buffer usage: [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/103590/438329), [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329), and [Use buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329).

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but that is not how I use vim. I usually have at least 3 different buffers open in a given tab (business logic, automated tests, and a terminal for test output). I add/remove more splits as needed, but if I have to switch focus I want to be able to move to a new workspace and then come back to the old one and have it look exactly how I left it. I find the visual queue of the window layout helps quite a bit with the cognitive load of context switching.

Comment: Great use of tabs. As an alternative and if you do no share buffers across tab pages you may want to look into using `:set switchbuf=usetab` and `:sb` to switch between buffers. See `:h 'swb'` and `:h :sb`. It isn't perfect but may provide some usefulness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no default way to do this. I looked into the ex command `tabnext`, which accepts a count, but functions exactly the same as `gt` (that is, it moves to tab page {count}, not {count} pages forward):

```
:tabn[ext] {count}
{count}<C-PageDown>
{count}gt   Go to tab page {count}.  The first tab page has number one.
```

However, this isn't very hard to configure! This vimscript mapping does what you're looking for:

```
nnoremap <leader>gt :<C-u>exec 'normal '.repeat("gt", v:count1)<cr>
```

This literally just simulates pressing `gt` over and over as many times as you need. With no count given, it will default to 1.

I picked `<leader>gt` somewhat arbitrarily. Of course, you can remap this to whatever is easiest or most convenient for you, whether it's a separate binding, or you choose to override the default `gt`.